# Sql Query for the following output

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

```
Table_1: (Name, Street, City)
Table_2: (Name, Teacher_Name)
```

The column Name in Table_1 contains Student's Name as well as Teacher's name while in Table_2 column Name contains only Student's Name and Teacher_Name contains Teacher's Name corresponding to the Student.

So my question is that what will be the SQl query for Finding all students who live in the same Street and City as their Teachers.

please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: mysql or sql-server? Please only tag the database engine you are actually using

Comment: i am using sql-server.

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Comment: @SolomonMinz Can you mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name
FROM Table_1 t1 INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
ON t1.Name = t2.Name
INNER JOIN Table_1 t3
ON t3.Name = t2.Teacher_Name
WHERE t1.Street = t3.Street AND t1.City = t3.City
```

You need to join twice to achieve what you want.  The first join is necessary to connect the address table with the bridge table of students to teachers.  Then you need to join again to get the addresses for those teachers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join Table_1 twice. Like so:

```
SELECT students.Name, teachers.Name
FROM Table_2 AS teacher_student
JOIN Table_1 AS students ON students.Name = teacher_student.Name
JOIN Table_1 AS teachers ON teachers.Name = teacher_student.Teacher_Name
WHERE students.Street = teachers.Street
AND students.City = teachers.City
```